# Setting the color for an individual data point

Tags: r, plot

How can I set the colour for  a single data point in  a scatter plot in `R`?

I am using `plot`

Comment: Do you want to plot all data points in particular color or just 1 specific data point?

Comment: i want to color specific data point in scatter plot.

Answer (score 39):

To expand on @Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer, you can use any function for `col` in the call to `plot`. For instance, this colors the `x==3` point red, leaving all others black:

```
x <- 1:5
plot(x, x, col=ifelse(x==3, "red", "black"))
```

[image: example 1]

Same goes for point character `pch`, character expansion `cex`, etc.

```
plot(x, x, col=ifelse(x==3, "red", "black"),
     pch=ifelse(x==3, 19, 1), cex=ifelse(x==3, 2, 1))
```

[image: example 2]

Comment: Yes, any _expression_ yielding a scalar or a recyclable vector.  So `col=c(rep("black",3), rep("blue", 2))` would have three black points followed by two blues.

Comment: Pretty simple but I never really thought about using ifelse here. thanks for sharing +1

Answer (score 20):

Doing what you want to do through code is easy enough and others have given nice ways to do this.  If, however, you would rather click on the points you want to change the color of you can do this by using 'identify' along with the 'points' command to replot over those points in a new color.

```
# Make some data
n <- 15
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)

# Plot the data
plot(x,y)

# This lets you click on the points you want to change
# the color of.  Right click and select "stop" when
# you have clicked all the points you want
pnt <- identify(x, y, plot = F)

# This colors those points red
points(x[pnt], y[pnt], col = "red")

# identify beeps when you click.
# Adding the following line before the 'identify' line will disable that.
# options(locatorBell = FALSE)
```

Comment: Also really cool dason.  Thank you for sharing, didn't think to use identify like that either. +1

Comment: identify is also very easy to use in R Studio.  Also good for labeling points.  But instead of right clicking to "stop" -- there is a button labeled stop in the R Studio plot preview.

Comment: @Captain On my version of RStudio it actually says "Finish"

Comment: That's right, sorry.  The red stop sign appears at the top of the console while identify is running.

Comment: Clicking the stop sign stops the actual process so (at least for me) this causes no value to be stored for the call the identify which defeats the purpose of it in the first place.  In my version of RStudio you need to use the "Finish" button to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `col=` argument which is *vectorized* so that eg in

```
 plot(1:5, 1:5, col=1:5)
```

you get five points in five different colors:

[image]

You can use the same logic to use just two or three colors among your data points. Understanding indexing is key in languages like R.

Comment: what about lines?(e.g.,some segment black,some segment red). it seems only the first element of col is used for 'plot(...,type = 'l',col = c('black','red',...)'