# How can I color data points in R based on a pattern match?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a data frame with this form:

```
             V1 V2                       V3          V4       V5         V6       V7           V8
1 0610007C21Rik  -   chr5:31351012-31356737 1.33732e-05 0.752381  0.9965090 0.000000 1.777419e-05
2 0610007L01Rik  - chr5:130695613-130717165 1.67168e+00 1.673120  0.0000000 3.453930 4.997847e-01
3 0610007P08Rik  -  chr13:63916627-64000808 7.06033e-01 0.000000  0.0815767 0.318051 1.000000e+00
4 0610007P14Rik  -  chr12:87157066-87165495 0.00000e+00 0.000000  0.0000000 5.494230          NaN
5 0610007P22Rik  -  chr17:25377114-25379603 4.99696e+00 0.908254  0.9076130 3.639250 8.461946e-01
6 0610009B22Rik  -  chr11:51499151-51502136 6.53363e-01 8.500980 13.5797000 0.000000 7.137192e-02
```

I am plotting log2(V4) vs. log2(V5) with this command:

```
plot(log2(df[,4]) ~ log2(df[,5]), xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
```

I want to color points based on a pattern match in V1. For instance, how can I color 0610007C21Rik and 0610007L01Rik green and 0610007P22Rik and 0610007P14Rik red?
I have tried adding another column to the data frame with a color specified, but there's got to be an easier way.

Comment: A possibly relevant question: [Color data point in R plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774002/color-data-point-in-r-plot)

Comment: This gets very close, but I'm having trouble integrating two conditions with separate colors.

`code`plot(x, x, col=ifelse(x==3, "red", "black"))

Comment: Any function can be provided to `col` in the call to `plot`, so you can write a custom function to do whatever you want using whatever data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base R solution:

Define your list of colours as a named vector once for each unique value of `df$V1`. Note the `""`'s around each of the names of points to be coloured.

```
col.list <- c(
              "0610007C21Rik"="green",
              "0610007L01Rik"="green",
              "0610007P22Rik"="red",
              "0610007P14Rik"="red"
             )
```

Then plot away using `df$V1` to look up the values in the `col.list` vector you have just defined.

```
plot(
     log2(df[,4]) ~ log2(df[,5]), 
     xlim=c(0,10),
     ylim=c(0,10),
     col=col.list[paste(df$V1)]
    )
```

To address the OP's comment below, use this in the `plot` call:

```
... col=ifelse(df$V1 %in% names(col.list),col.list[paste(df$V1)],"black")
```

This makes the full call look like:

```
plot( 
      log2(df[,4]) ~ log2(df[,5]),
      xlim=c(0,10),
      ylim=c(0,10),
      col=ifelse(df$V1 %in% names(col.list),col.list[paste(df$V1)],"black")
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close to what I wanted to achieve. However, it doesn't plot the points that weren't specified in col.list. Since the full data frame has over 20,000 rows, how can I get it to plot everything not mentioned in col.list in black?

Comment: @JoshuaA - see my edit above which I think solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ggplot2 package.

If you dput your data frame it will make it easier for people to help with code.

Here is one example with made up data that looks a bit like yours, there are better ways to log transform however.

```
df <- data.frame(sample(LETTERS[1:5],20, replace=TRUE), abs(rnorm(20)/100), abs(runif(20)*10))
colnames(df) <- c('V1','V4','V5')


library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(log2(V4) , log2(V5)))
p + geom_point(aes(colour = V1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want to supply a unique color to each row, since there are over 20,000 in the full data frame. Specifically what I want to do is make 10 of those green and nineteen of those red based on the entry in V1. In my short example, how could I make 0610007C21Rik and 0610007L01Rik green and 0610007P22Rik and 0610007P14Rik red by searching the first column for those entries?