# how to mark each data point in a plot with its label and user specified color?

Tags: r

I have the following two dimensional data points, the first column is data ID

```
ID    V1              V2
1   -9.2523712  1.751943612
2   -0.9799493  0.067998776
3   -0.9799493  0.067998776
4   3.2156859   1.088934239
5   3.4915597   1.097911743
6   3.4915597   1.097911743
7   -0.9799493  0.067998776
8   -0.9799493  0.067998776
9   -0.9799493  0.067998776
10  3.2156859   1.088934239
```

Assume this array is named as `fit`, I plot these points  as `plot(fit[,2],fit[,3])` However, is that possible to mark each point with its ID on the plot? In addition, for some specific point, like ID 10, I would like to mark it with red color. How can I do that in R?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot with conditional colors based on values in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838278/plot-with-conditional-colors-based-on-values-in-r) and [setting-the-color-for-an-individual-data-point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774002/setting-the-color-for-an-individual-data-point)

Comment: Your points are all essentially on top of one another. It might be worth looking here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611169/intelligent-point-label-placement-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after your plot command, use the following:

```
text(x=fit[, 2], y=fit[, 3], labels=fit[, 1])
points(x=fit[fit$ID==10, 2], y=fit[fit$ID==10, 3], col="red")
```

That being said, much nicer in ggplot

Comment: Using `pch=19` on both the original `plot` call and the `points` call will make things a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try jittering the points using `letters[i]` to label the ith point and superimpose that on a sunflower plot whose red spokes show multiplicities.  We can play with the random seed and jitter parameters to tweak it.  Point a has no overlaid points but there are five overlaid (b, c, g, h, i) near the bottom and there are four overlaid (d, e, f, j) near the right side as we can see from the plot.

```
set.seed(19)
fitj <- transform(fit, V1 = jitter(V1, 10), V2 = jitter(V2), 10)
with(fit, sunflowerplot(V1, V2))
with(fitj, text(V1, V2, letters[1:10]))
```

[image: screenshot]